# JSON url response null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsurlsession

I write an application for iphone in objective-c and wanna get data from json. but I get null from url, but url is correct and when I pass url to browser I see the json data. this is my IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)checkMobileNumber:(id)sender {
    NSString *prefix = self.prefixTextField.text;
    NSString *number = self.numberTextField.text;
    NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://data.e-gov.az/api/v1/IEGOVService.svc/CheckMobileProvider/%@/%@", prefix, number];
    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    @try {
        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:jsonURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSString* rawJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *err;
            self.checkMobile = [[CheckMobileProviderModel alloc] initWithString:rawJSON error:nil];
            if (err) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to initialize PublicPhotosModel, %@", err.localizedDescription);
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"%@", self.checkMobile.response);
                //NSLog(@"%@", self.checkMobile.fault[@"faultString"]);
            });
        }] resume];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
}
```

what is wrong here? any help?

EDIT:

my CheckMobileProviderModel.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "FaultModel.h"

@protocol FaultModel
@end

@interface CheckMobileProviderModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *response;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<FaultModel, Optional>* fault;

@end
```

and FaultModel.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@interface FaultModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* faultCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* faultString;

@end
```

Comment: First, I assume `jsonURL` was not `nil`. Second, inside `completionHandler`, was `data` non-`nil`? Was the `error` reference `nil`? Third, what the `statusCode` of the `response`? We really need to see what `data`, `error`, and `response` were...

Comment: when I debug the code, point from NSURLSession point jump to the end of block and I can't get the values of data, response and error. but the jsonURL is not nil, his value is = http://data.e-gov.az/api/v1/IEGOVService.svc/CheckMobileProvider/050/2543611

Comment: Set your breakpoint _inside_ the `completionHandler` block and you'll have access to those variables.

Comment: Unrelated, but you're probably coming from an environment where exception handlers is an accepted error handling mechanism, but it is not best practice in Cocoa. Exceptions are for development errors that must be remedied before you ship your app, not for runtime errors.

Comment: yes, I get the values when put breakpoint inside. So, error is nil, data and response are not nil. in rawJSON I get this string = {\"fault\":{\"faultCode\":1,\"faultString\":\"Məlumat yoxdur\"},\"response\":\"Cari nömrə üçün mobil daşınma xidmətindən istifadə edilməmişdir\"}
maybe I get nil because of this slash symbols?

Comment: The slashes may have been added in the process of printing the string and might not really be part of the data. When you call `NSJSONSerialization`, what `NSError` object do you get from that?

Comment: I edited the question and showed u my model for JSONModel. and I want to note, that when I start the app first 2 times, everything was OK, after the third start I got nil

Comment: OK, if you're getting `nil`, you gotta look at the `NSError` object. Everything you need to diagnose what's going on is right there. (Just make sure that you're checking `checkMobile` _inside_ the block, not after it, because it gets updated asynchronously.)

Comment: the problem was in my CheckMobileProviderModel class in parameter @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<FaultModel, Optional>* fault; and now I don't have idea how to use fault section from my json.

Comment: Why do you define the value `err` and never set it?  And you never look at the value of `error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not convert the JSON to a string:
`NSString* rawJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
convert it is an object, in this case a NSDictionary

```
NSError = *error;
NSDictionary  *dict = [NSJSONSerialization  JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (dict) {
    NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

The JSON in the comment nicely formatted:

```
{
    "fault":{
        "faultCode":1,
        "faultString":"Məlumat yoxdur"
        },
    response":"Cari nömrə üçün mobil daşınma xidmətindən istifadə edilməmişdir"
}
```

Translated:

```
{
    "fault":{
        "faultCode":1,
        "faultString":"there is no information"
        },
    response":"The current number is not used for a mobile carriage service"
}
```